# JSHint plugin for Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, jslint, jshint

Is there a JSHint plugin for Eclipse? I can't find anything on Google.

Answer (score 13):

You can try [jshint-eclipse](http://github.eclipsesource.com/jshint-eclipse/)

I created this plug-in for use in the Eclipse RAP project. It's still in its early days but already works fine and lets you configure JSHint as needed.

Comment: As of Feb 2014 JSHint-Eclipse is very stable plugin, including JSHint 2.1.10

Comment: Very late here, but how do I get it to work? I followed the instructions on the website, but I couldn't see any errors if I create any.

Comment: In the context menu on your project, configure the directories that should be checked by JSHint. Project properties > JSHint

Answer (score 1):

I did a JSLint Eclipse plug-in right before JSHint came out. It includes options to disable some of the more bothersome JSLint errors, like not erroring out from a var declaration in a for loop.

It's one of the packages available at https://svn.codespot.com/a/eclipselabs.org/mobile-web-development-with-phonegap/tags/r1.2/download

Comment: 2 year later project page http://code.google.com/a/eclipselabs.org/p/mobile-web-development-with-phonegap/ still points to r1.2 version.

Comment: The latest release there is 1.2.91 from July 5, 2012 which is still meeting the needs of many. But if jshint-eclipse is an active development, may be a better option.

Comment: Please create Marketplace entry for JSLint Eclipse

Comment: It's here http://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/applaud-phonegap-android-jslintjshint#.UwqxqUJdVF4